# What does "leave the pass" mean?

Tags: meaning

**Everything that leaves the pass has my name on it, so I’m always making sure my staff stay on their toes and perform at the top of their ability.**

It's a quote from Gordon Ramsay (https://www.scribd.com/doc/8166720/Gordon-Ramsay), and what does "leave the pass" mean here? Does it mean just "pass"?

Additionally, what does "stay on their toe" mean? Does it mean to "stay sharp"?

Comment: Ramsay could have used a less jargon-filled remark like: "Everything that leaves the *kitchen* has my name on it..."

Comment: Gordon Ramsay is famous for saying exactly what he likes. It is likely that most of the readers of that article know exactly what the pass in a restaurant is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pass, as I understand it, is a term in the restaurant business that is the place the plates are placed by kitchen staff so that the waiters can pick them up and deliver them to diners. "Leave the pass" means "picked up by a waiter" so Ramsey is saying that because diners will associate any imperfection with him personally (because his name is on the restaurant) he expects high performance by his staff. And yes, "stay on their toes" means the same as "stay sharp" or to be highly aware of their surroundings.

Comment: The pass is the bit of a restaurant where the chef stands glowering over finished dishes before letting the waiters take them into the dining room. -- (Restaurant review in the _Guardian_)